# I am not able to find my device_code.defconfig file in config folder of the source

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, android-kernel

I am trying to compile/build a custom kernel for "Asus_zenfone_max pro_m1"  so i have downloaded the kernel source from the manufacturer's website but i see that there is no "defconfig" file present for X00T (my device code name) in the "kernel/arch/arm64/configs" folder so i tried different available config files but none of it is working. So can anybody please tell me how can i get that device specific "defconfig" file in order to build a custom kernel for the device?